# Assuming a randomly generated set of natural numbers, and we start counting from the first element......

Tags: probability, statistics

what is the probability that, at some given time, we've counted at least 5% of the elements of the set?

Assume we can not see, at any point during the counting, the number of remaining elements.

Suppose the cardinality of the randomly generated set is $N$. So each value of $N$ is equally likely. Suppose we are at $k$ at some point of the counting. Using law of total probability:

$$P(k\geq 0.05N)=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=k}^{20k} \frac{1}{N} P(k\geq 0.05N | N=n) $$

$$=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=k}^{20k} \frac{1}{N}=0$$

So the answer is 0. But what's wrong with this argument?:

Since we know nothing about $N$, we are equally likely to have counted any fraction of $N$ at any given time. So the probability that we've counted at least 5% of the elements at some point in time is 95%

Comment: One problem you'll run into is that there's no right way to make sense of "each value of $N$ is equally likely." This is because there is no uniform probability measure on the naturals.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins So is it non-sensical to talk about a randomly generated set of natural numbers? We can use probability density, right?

Comment: It's not nonsense, but there's no one right way to talk about the probability of a subset of the natural numbers. For example, what is the probability of a number having a leading $1$ in its decimal expansion? You might say it should be $1/9$, but of the $199$ numbers between $1$ and $199$, $111$ have a leading $1$.

Comment: @CharlesHudhins Is this problem vague then? Or is the 95% answer correct somehow?